# Simple Library of YouTube Videos Which Play in JW Player When Clicked

Tags: ios, video, youtube, jwplayer

I have some text links to YouTube videos on a mobile version of a website. In iOS when I click on of the links, the video plays in the YouTube App.

Problem is when the video finishes, the user is left to find there way back to the original webpage.

We are using JW Player on the desktop site & elsewhere on the mobile site.

Is there a way of writing the text link so that the JW PLayer is fired instead of sending users to the YouTube app?

Comment: Right now the JW Player uses the default YouTube embed player on mobile. We are moving to YouTube HTML5 officially for 6.8 though, due out in Q1 next year.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default Mobile Safari detects youtube links and redirects you to the youtube app if you have it (At least this used to be the case, I'm not so sure now its not a default app).

What you can do is find all the youtube links and then add a click handler to them which opens up the video with jwplayer and prevents the default action of opening the Youtube app.

```
var youtubeLinks = $('a').filter(youtubeHrefFilter);

youtubeLinks.each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        youtubePlayer('player', this.href);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function youtubePlayer(element, url) {
    jwplayer(element).setup({file: url});
};

function youtubeHrefFilter() {
    return extractYoutubeLinks(this.href) != null;
};

function extractYoutubeLinks(text) {
    return text.match(/youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/);
};
```

A working example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9HA6j/143/